# PowerBI Creating embed token for accessing dataset shouldn't have effective identity

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am getting error while trying to generate embed token for Power BI dashboards embedded in a custom app

```
POST : https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/dashboards/{dashboardId}/GenerateToken
```

Request Body

```
 {
      "accessLevel": "View",
      "identities": [
        {
          "datasets": [
            "f7b28b55-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-93bcb5067f50"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Creating embed token for accessing dataset f7b28b55-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-93bcb5067f50 shouldn't have effective identity"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If we read error message carefully it has been mentioned "shouldn't have effective identity", which simply means it should not require identity to be passed in request body, API invocation will work after removing identities section like below :

```
{
  "accessLevel": "View"
}
```